# How do you choose a value in conditional statement randomly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, conditional-statements

The following is an example:

```
p_dur_same = [0, 5, 5]
activity = [2, 3, 4]
max_p_dur_same = max(p_dur_same)
```

The thing that I have to do is to choose the highest value in p_dur_same, then get its index and use this index to find its corresponding activity number.

I have a conditional part in my code that goes like this:

```
    # if same duration, randomly choose between the activities in activity 
    if p_dur_same.count(max_p_dur_same) > 1:
       select_act =
       p_dur_select_act =
    else:
    # if different, select the activity that has the highest duration
       select_act =
       p_dur_select_act = [d for a, d in zip(activity, p_dur_same) if a in select_act]
    print(select_act)
    print(p_dur_select_act)
```

I would just like to ask for help in how to choose randomly between the activities that has the same value for `max_p_dur_same`. And, how do you find the index of the `max(p_dur_same)` then use that index to find the corresponding value in `activity`. Note that, `activity` is a numpy array in my code.

For the example above, I should get something like:

Since `max(p_dur_same)` appears more than once, then we have to randomly select between the two `(5s in p_dur same)`. Let's say it selects the 1st one, then `select_act = 3` `p_dur_select_act = 5`. I could get this by getting the index of the 1st 5 in `p_dur_same`, then using this index to find corresponding value in `activity`.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the max entries in the list along with their indices and later use `random` module to choose an item randomly from list. This item holds index and the random max element. Use the index to get the corresponding value from `activity`:

```
import random

p_dur_same = [0, 5, 5]
activity = [2, 3, 4]

max_p_dur_same = max(p_dur_same)   
maxs = [(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(p_dur_same) if x == max_p_dur_same]
# [(1, 5), (2, 5)]

k = random.choice(maxs)
# (1, 5)

p_dur_select_act = k[1]
select_act = activity[k[0]]

print(p_dur_select_act, select_act)
# 5 3
```

Comment: Hello! Can I just ask what does these lines mean? p_dur_select_act = k[1]
select_act = activity[k[0]] ? Sorry for the bother! I just want to understand it.

Comment: Thank you! What I did is to put that part on the first conditional part. For instances that there the number in p_dur_same are unique, like p_dur_same = [0, 5, 3], how could I choose the highest, get the highest index and use this to find the corresponding activity?

Comment: Should I still include the random part on that code? I though that that random only works for if they have the same values? Sorry, if I keep asking question. I just want to understand and learn more in coding since I am very new to Python.

Comment: Even there is only one highest value or many, this approach works. Because randomly selecting from list with one value returns the same value. So that comes down to discarding your `if` structure.

Comment: Oh that means I don't have to put  it in a conditional statement anymore since no matter what the p_dur_same is it will still work! Thank you so much!